# One query to display tags for item

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, tags

I have a problem with merging two queries into one. My example database looks like this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b2hsQiqzfqrDhRXzRmM49m/4

I would like to give out all the items matching the first query and their tags:

title, description, tags // Query #3 in link

The main problem with which I have a problem is the transfer of data from one query to another. item.iditem = 112, where 112 is the idit from the first query. My attempt:

```
SELECT title, description, i.idItem
FROM tags t INNER JOIN
     itemtags it
     ON t.idTag = it.idtag INNER JOIN
     item i ON it.idItem = i.idItem
WHERE t.name = "java";

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`Name`) as tags
FROM tags
WHERE idtag IN ( SELECT it.idtag FROM itemtags it,tags t WHERE it.idtag=t.idtag AND it.iditem = 112);

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT title, description FROM tags t INNER JOIN itemtags it ON t.idTag = it.idtag INNER JOIN item i ON it.idItem = i.idItem WHERE t.name = "java") as x, 
     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`Name`) as tags FROM tags JOIN itemtags ON tags.idtag = itemtags.idtag INNER JOIN item ON itemtags.iditem = item.iditem AND item.iditem = 112) as y;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt:

It displays the **title** and the **description** of each item that has a tag named "java", plus a column containing a concatenation of all the tags recorded for that item.

You can change the conditional tag name `"java"` to other names to display items having a specific tag by changing the condition `WHERE t.name="java"` to `WHERE t.name="frontend"` for example.

**Notice:** I had to use `DISTINCT` at the start of the outer `SELECT` query and inside the `GROUP_CONCAT` function to ignore duplicate records in the `itemtags` table in the example database you provided.

I tested the query in db-fiddle too:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b2hsQiqzfqrDhRXzRmM49m/13

```
SELECT DISTINCT itemDetails.title, itemDetails.description, allTags.allTags_tags as tags 
FROM item
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT i.iditem, i.title, i.description
    FROM item i
    inner join itemtags it 
    on i.iditem = it.iditem 
    inner join tags t 
    on it.idtag = t.idtag 
    WHERE t.name="java"
) as itemDetails
ON itemDetails.iditem = item.iditem
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT i.iditem as allTags_iditem, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.name) as allTags_tags  
    FROM item i 
    inner join itemtags it 
    on i.iditem = it.iditem 
    inner join tags t 
    on it.idtag = t.idtag   
    GROUP BY it.iditem 
) as allTags
ON itemDetails.iditem = allTags.allTags_iditem;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to show the logic just using ids.  You can fill in the rest of the query to handle names with additional joins.

The idea is a self join and then aggregation.  The key is to count the number of matching tags, to see if the number of matches covers all the tags for the item in question:

```
select it.idItem
from itemtags it join
     itemtags itj
     on it.idtag = itj.idtag and itj.iditem = 112
group by it.idItem
having count(*) = (select count(*)
                   from itemtags itj
                   where itj.idItem = 112
                  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Unfortunately, but I do not quite understand. The data that I have given is "java" and 112 must be defined by the first query. The 112 number is just an example to make requests in the link work. I do not quite understand how your query will lead me to a solution.